# Как вывести в Fancybox главное изображение ноды?

Tags: drupal, fancybox

Добрый день!

Есть сайт на Drupal 7.3 на котором выводятся товары, [вот например](http://vinokuram.ru/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA%D1%81%C2%BB-17%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

У ноды есть главная картинка и вторичные картинки (внизу).

По ТЗ, требуется чтобы fancyBox работал не только на картинки внизу, но и на "главную" картинку ноды. В админке создан тип материала "Товар" со стандартным полем "Изображение" (field_image, формат поля fancybox, поле многокартиночное), но ковыряние в его настройках так и не позволяет сделать чтобы главная картинка также обзавелась фансибоксом.

В коде шаблона вижу следующее, в чем мне кажется ключ к разгадке:

а) для картинки которая не увеличивается по клику php-код:

```
print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => '250x350', 'path' => $content['field_image']['#items'][0]['uri']));
```

б) для блока картинкок, которые увеличиваются:

```
print render($content['field_image']);
```

Проблема в том, как из этого field_image вытащить одну картинку с теми же свойствами фэнсибокса что и у всего блока и корректно ее отображать. Колдовал по-разному, пытался var_dump'ом глядеть что к чему в этих массивах, без толку(

Answer (score 2):

У вас срока:

```
print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => '250x350', 'path' => $content['field_image']['#items'][0]['uri']));
```

выводит просто картинку.

Вам же нужна ссылка на нее с классом fancybox что бы fancyBox заработал.

```
"<a href=".$content['field_image']['#items'][0]['uri']." class ='fancybox'>".print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => '250x350', 'path' => $content['field_image']['#items'][0]['uri'])) ."</a>";
```

Это выведет превью в качестве ссылкой на основное изображение.